# Ambient isotopic in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Based on the image above :

Which of the objects are ambient isotopic in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Which of the objects are ambient isotopic in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ?

Which of the objects are homeomorphic ?

**Definition**

This is new chapter for my topology course and I want to know how to determine ambient isotopy in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. Ambient isotopy means :

Let $X$ be atopological space

Let $A,B \subset X$. $A$ and $B$ are called ambient isotopy if there is a function

$$h:X \times [0,1] \to X$$

and it defines

$$h_t:X \to X$$ for each $t \in [0,1]$, by $h_t(x)=x$ such that :

(a) $h_0 : X \to X$ is identify

(b) at each $t \in [0,1]$, $h_t : X \to X$ is homeomorphism

(c) $h_1(A)=B$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images 1,2 and 5 are homeomorphic. While 3 and 4 are homeomorphic. Can you see why?

Now an ambient isotopy is a continuous deformation of one picture to another, and in particular they need to be homeomorphic. So we must see whether any pair of 1,2,5 have such a deformation and whether 3 can be deformed to 4. Actually the fact that 3 can be deformed to 4 is not so hard to see. Lengthen the short arc of the circle and contract the long arc, until the straight line segment is dragged around to the other side of the plus sign.

To see that 5 is not ambient isotopic, note that the line segment points to the inside of the circle, and any ambient isotopy of $\mathbb R^2$ would preserve this. So 5 cannot be ambient isotopic to either 1 or 2. To distinguish 1 and 2, note that travelling clockwise around the circle, you meet the line segment and plus sign in a different order, and clockwise spin is something that is preserved by ambient isotopy. Hence they can't be related. The difference in this argument from the pair (3,4) is that although direction of spin is well-defined, which of the two external doodads you hit first is not intrinsically defined by the (3,4) pictures.

For $\mathbb R^3$, 1,2 and 5 are all ambient isotopic. You can imagine them being made out of wire. You can bend the doodads attached to the circle to be in any of the three positions.